# Using dcolumn for tables: Alignment on decimal and thousands separator

Tags: tables, dcolumn, alignment

I'm struggling to align numbers on the decimal (`.`) as well as thousands (`,`) separator using `dcolumn`. I'd like to avoid unnecessary space when displaying decimals in one, and thousands in another row of the same column (see column X). Also, the alignment in column Y row B is wrong and I don't know how to fix this.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn} 
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2.3}}           % alignment on decimal marker
\newcolumntype{e}{D{,}{,}{2.3}}           % alignment on thousand marker
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % shorthand macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\centering 
\begin{threeparttable} 
\caption{Some Caption} 
\begin{tabular}{lde} 
\toprule     
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{All}} \\  
          & \mc{X} & \mc{Y} \\   
\midrule 
A         &  0.97  & 33,635 \\ 
B         & 27.17  & 500    \\ 
C         & 11.40  & 33,635 \\ 
\midrule 
N         & 90,234 & 33,635 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes} 
\small 
\item Some notes. 
\end{tablenotes} 
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you don't need to align on the thousand marker just right align (or align on the non existing decimal point)

Comment: @zarko you deleted your answer? (it looked like the right answer to me:-)